# Matlab filtering two strings to make them equal

Tags: string, matlab

I need to compare two character arrays and make them exactly the same. At the same time, I need the coordinates of the characters I kept.

For example, I have two character arrays

```
A=['a';'b';'b';'b';'c';'d'];
B=['a';'b';'b';'d'];
```

I want the result to be

```
Anew=['a';'b';'b';'d'];
Bnew=['a';'b';'b';'d'];
```

and I want to know the positions

```
APos=[1;2;3;6];
BPos=[1;2;3;4];
```

So that

```
Anew=A(APos);
Bnew=B(BPos);
```

I tried the following code

```
[lmod1,lmod2]=size(A);
[lobs1,lobs2]=size(B);

PosB=zeros(lobs1,1);

for i=1:lobs1
    for j=1:lmod1
        if B(i,:)==A(j,:)
            PosB(i,:)=i; %collect the ones that are in there, the zeros should then be the ones that are not 
        end
    end
end

PosB2=PosB(PosB~=0);

PosA=zeros(lmod1,1);
for i=1:lmod1
    for j=1:lobs1
        if A(i,:)==B(j,:)% if this is true at the end of the loop, it means that the value of namesobs is in namesw
            PosA(i,:)=i; %collect the ones that are in there, the zeros should then be the ones that are not 
        end
    end
end

PosA2=PosA(PosA~=0);
```

But this only checks for presence, not if the values are repeated a different amount of times. How do I add an extra filter so the strings are repeated the same amount of times in both string arrays?

FYI the actual strings I am working with look like this:

```
>> ODates(1:10,:)

ans =

  10×12 char array

    '20100202_186'
    '20100202_186'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_191'
    '20100202_191'
    '20100202_191'
```

> > EDates(1:10,:)

```
ans =

  10×12 char array

    '20100202_186'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
```

And then the answer would be:

> > NewDates(1:10,:)

```
ans =

  10×12 char array

    '20100202_186'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
    '20100202_190'
```

Comment: quick question: you said, the strings should be made the same but ´all(A(APos) == B(BPos))´ is false because there are 3 ´'b'´s in `A` and you said, the result that you want to have is `APos=[1;2;3;5;6];`... now could you clarify what you want?

Comment: @max that was a typo thank you ´APos = [1;2;3;6];´

Comment: Are there any limitations on what kind of strings can appear? Something like always in alphabetic order? If a caracter is present multiple times, they are next to each other? The generic case can be solved, but such information would make it much easier.

Comment: @Daniel I added an example of what my actual char array looks like.

Comment: I am a little surprised to see such an example. Let's say you have '20100202_123' and '20100123_456', the result would be '20100123', is this wat you want?

Comment: @Daniel, no sorry I didn't explain it clearly I made another edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track by solving this through looping but I feel that you were thinking a bit too complicated. Check out this solution

```
A=['a';'b';'b';'b';'c';'d'];
B=['a';'b';'b';'d'];

% allocate logical vectors
lgA = false(size(A));
lgB = false(size(B));

% initialize loop control counter
ia0 = 1;
% looping
for ib = 1:length(B)
    for ia = ia0:length(A)
        % check if A == B and stop the looping over A if it is true
        if A(ia) == B(ib)
            % store 
            lgA(ia) = true;
            lgB(ib) = true;
            % update loop control counter to start from the current
            % index the next time
            ia0 = ia+1;
            break
        end
    end
end
% validity check
assert( all(A(lgA) == B(lgB)) )
% output
APos = find(lgA);
BPos = find(lgB);
```

Comment: This returns a correct solution, but not the longest match. Try `A=['a';'b';'c';'d';'e';'z'];
B=['a';'z';'b';'c';'d';'e'];`. I am sure there is no optimal greedy algorithm for this question.

Comment: That is correct @Daniel . It assumes that you want to find the first match. If you want to find the longest, you will have to pack that in an additional loop over `B` altering the initial position of the `for ib`-loop